# Install freezes "GRUB UEFI enabling NVRAM updates" server 18.04 LTS

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 onto my server and it hangs on this message every time: [the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW3qs.jpg)

```
GRUB UEFI enabling NVRAM updates
Running command ['sh', '-c', 'exec "$)" $@" 2>&1', 'ini-grub', '--uefi', '--update-nvram', '--os-family=debian' '/target', '/dev/sda'] with accepting return codes [0] (capture=True)
```

Specs:

- Mobo: Intel 5500HCV 2x socket 1366 (yes, it has EFI)
- CPU: 2x Intel Xeon E5620 @ 2.4GHz
- RAM: 36GB DDR3-1333 ECC
- HDD: Western Digital Blue 6TB HDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I didn't exactly solve the root problem, but... I got a 250gb ssd and installed it using legacy while having my 6tb as GPT.  Now everything works as intended.